# protoc --dart_out=grpc:. -Iprotos helloworld.proto - directory does not exist

Tags: dart, grpc, protoc

How do you specify a directory - the following only work if I put my `helloworld.proto` in a folder named `protos`

```
protoc --dart_out=. -Iprotos helloworld.proto
protos: warning: directory does not exist.
helloworld.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to include `-I` in this case because `helloworld.proto` is in the current working directory.

`-I` (proto path) is used by `protoc` to reference directories that aren't in the current working directory. If you were to use `${PWD}/helloworld.proto` for example, I think you'd need need to `-I=${PWD}`. Even though `${PWD}` is equivalent to the current working directory, `protoc` sees a proto with a directory prefix and expects it to be added to the proto path.

Customarily, you'd need to add a proto path when you have protobuf imports that aren't local. Then, you add `-I=` and list the directories where these imports may be found.